# State-of-the-art animated handwritten slideshow software

Tags: presentation, software, online-resource

This is a remake/sequel of the 2015 question [Handwritten presentation slides?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/46302/42337).
Surely much has changed in these five years. I have seen lots of presentations combining typed text/equations and handwritten diagrams, sometimes on the same slide. Technically it would not be difficult to do it "by hand" - say, work with TeX/beamer or powerpoint, draw pictures, make image files and include them as graphics into your slides. However I would like to have two more features:

First and foremost, to automate this. Say, I make slides, leave out some space, then review the slides and draw inside the left out space. Or something probably even more efficient?

Second, I would like to include animated sequences, like a drawing gradually showing up, or being modified in a simple way - say, some lines disappearing and new ones appearing on the same drawing.

Do you know good efficient software for that? Or maybe you can just suggest efficient search terms for googling it? What I try seems to be too general, I get lots of results but none of them are to the point.

Comment: Many of the answers to the old question say "don't" or "use beamer instead" and I think that's still valid.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist Unless I overlooked something, the main reasons of these "don't"s were that (a) handwriting is hard to recognize and (b) it is difficult to modify it afterwards. I believe (a) does not apply here as I am going to use typewritten text and only use handwriting for drawings/diagrams; as for (b), this might be part of the request - that I could easily modify the included drawings.

Comment: You can draw on a blank slide with the pen / brush tools that exist already - of course if your hand is not steady then the results can be poor.

Comment: @SolarMike What if I need to combine the drawing with typed text? And how can I record dynamically modifications in the drawing?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @SolarMike I tried out several apps like liveboard, Microsoft whiteboard, Google slides, but either they lack functionality I need (like entering math formulas) or simply do not allow for freehand drawing inside a slide

Comment: PowerPoint allows for freehand writing during a presentation?

Comment: I don't think it's allowed to write a question here even if the answers have dramatically changed. I read something on Travel Meta about this.

Comment: @user111388 What do you mean exactly? Could you provide a link? Usually if some people believe that this is a duplicate of another question, they just mark it as a duplicate.

Comment: I mean this: https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6692/what-is-the-best-way-to-treat-an-out-of-date-community-wiki-answer I think this question herw should be closed as a duplicate even though the other question might be useless and one should hope that the other question gets updated (which is not very likely).

Comment: @user111388 OK thanks. I think I will still leave this one open, as it contains additional details that the other one does not.

Comment: @IanSudbery Thanks, yes, you are right, I just checked. If not for formulas I would probably use this one. I think you should make it an answer. Not that I would surely accept it as THE answer, but...